# About string datatype in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string

I have a `String` variable in VB.NET and it contains a value like

```
"Date of    9/23/2012  Tot Sec_sale Amt = 29,22,696RM's Wise  ,  Gunadeep=15,83,876 ,  Purushothaman C.S.=1,12,829 ,  P.madhusudhanreddy=4,63,933 ,  Sunil vakayil=6,31,120 ,  Girish Varghese=33,019 ,  Debarun Chakraborty=79,288 ,  Rajiv Varma=18,630, RM's DT Count 1,342"
```

In application side I am able to view this value. I stored this value in MySQL table column. That column contains a `longtext` datatype. But I am not able to view the full content. Not able to view the last part `RM's DT Count 1,342`. It shows like `Rm's...`.

My table structure:

```
fld_msg longtext
fld_phone   varchar(20)
fld_date    date
fld_status  varchar(45)
fld_type    varchar(45)
fld_name    varchar(50)
```

My VB.NET code:

```vb
Dim bh_msg As String =
    "Date of    " + Convert.ToDateTime(txt1.Text).Date +
    "  Tot Sec_sale Amt = " + strdmy_bh_sec_amt.ToString +
    "RM's Wise " + bh_amt_frmt1.ToString + "," +
    " RM's DT Count " + str_bh_dt_count.ToString
```

Comment: Where are you trying to view the value? How is the column defined in the database?

Comment: What code you've used to insert values? (Is it parameterized sql?)

Comment: @oded in mysql am try to view the colum value(fld_msg)

Comment: @AVD my insert the bh_msg string variable value into mysql table colum fld_msg

Comment: Verify the `data` at database side. Are they inserted/added properly?

Comment: Try getting the value out in C# - I am guessing you are simply seeing what the mySql IDE is showing (for usability), not the actual stored value.

Comment: @ AVD ok i ll check pls wait in on line

Comment: @AVD ya,its inserted correctly.but the string variable value last part is not able to view

Comment: Not sure about what is equivalent in MySql to retrieve data as xml but in SQL server we look towards xml using `for xml path`query to extract `unlimited` data. Try to get data, this way.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to store a message like that in db. Instead, the table should have columns for each of the individual data points in the string. Reproduce the full formatted string when you take the data back out, not when you first put it in.

Answer (score 1):

Most DB Viewer truncate long texts fields (blob, clob, ...) in order to maintain performances. But that's just debug view. The real data, and your program, should use the entire value.

Try to retrieve those values using your VB code. It should work